# Dynamic array and pointer in a class trouble finding the right way to define them

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, header, header-files

I want the constructor to create a dynamic array and assign arguments passed to the constructor to the members of the array.

A simplified version of what I have in the header:

```
//in classes.h
#ifndef classes_h
#define classes_h
#include <iostream>
class Base{
        int a,*var;
public:
    Base();
    Base(int);
    ~Base();
    int func(int);
};
#endif
```

And in the *.cpp:

```
//In classes.cpp
#incldue "classes.h"
Base::Base(int a){
    var=new int[2];
    var[0]=a;
    var[1]=func(a);
}
Base::~Base(){
        delete var;
}
int Base::func(int b){
    return b++;
}
int main(){
Base obj(1);
return 0;}
```

I need to be able to pass that array to a function which will modify it in some way, but I'm actually having more trouble defining the array...

I don't get any errors from the compiler or linker, but by debugging I arrived at the conclusion the problem is around the creation of the array.

I went over the basics of pointers, dynamic arrays and classes 3 (or maybe more) times, but to no avail. I'm hoping what I'm trying to do is actually possible. If not, what's the closest thing?

Comment: delete [] var; otherwise memory leak

Comment: Please don't fix one error at a time in your code, rendering existing answers obsolete.

Comment: Yes, sorry, was going to unfix it, but it was gone already.

Comment: The statement `return b++;` return the _current_ value of `b` and _then_ increase the _local_ variable. So if you pass the value `1` to `func` it will return `1`. Maybe you want `++b`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Definitely! Order of operation, much easier with a+=1... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. You are not following the **[Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)**.
2. You have an **Undefined Behavior**.

Details:

```
delete var;
```

should be:

```
delete []var;
```

`new` requires `delete` and `new[]` requires `delete []`, a mismtach results in Undefined Behavior.

**Suggestion:**

You should be using a `std::vector` or `std::array` instead of an dynamic c-style array. It will save you all the efforts and they are less error prone.

Comment: So my problem lies in the shallow copies?

Comment: @wizzard: Yes, Indeed. Technically, Your code has Undefined Behavior, but usually that will result in memory leak not the said behavior.

Comment: Gonna educate myself further into c++ by reading more on the Rule of Three and return shortly.

Answer (score 1):

You're running into undefined behavior because of

```
var=new int[2];
```

being freed with

```
delete var;
```

instead of `delete[] var;`.

You should use a `std::vector<int>` instead. That way, you needn't worry about a destructor/copy constructor/assignment operator.

Also, note that

```
int Base::func(int b){
    return b++;
}
```

is basically a no-op, as the previous value of `b` is returned. Did you mean `return b+1`?

Comment: is there really no other way to do it without ::vector?

Comment: @wizzard sure there is, it's called "the hard way".

Comment: There is a multitude of reasons as to why `std::vector<T, Alloc>` makes dynamics arrays far less painful than hand-coding. Unless you have a solid reason for avoiding it, **don't**.

Comment: My reason is to understand why it's not working the way it is right now. I decided to 'refresh' my memories on c++, but it turned out they were all long gone... (the language has become prettier last 4-5 years). Decided to make a simple 3D array, turned out it's not simple at all, looked around, found boost, turns up I have a problem defining the arguments I pass to boost, came here to ask after being unable to find anything related to my problem. Turns out My problem is even more basic than I thought :D

Comment: @wizzard 1. you don't tell us exactly where the problem is. 2. Did you notice that `func` does nothing?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore 2 was supposed to be just some function a `def f():pass` in Python if you will. Anyway, It must be what Als suggested, gonna look up the Copy constructor and Copy assignment operator edit my script a bit and report back with the good news or any further problems I encounter :)  Thanks for the timely responses :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like vectors in this example you could use a std::pair but a vector is the way to go. I haven't used an array in months.